# Can I get the members of a facebook group I am not admin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a member of a closed group. Not admin. Can I get the list of all members of a group with [facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/group)?
I read I need "user_managed_groups". do I? I got confused whether I can list all members of a group I am not an admin or not?

Answer (score 1):

`user_managed_groups` is for getting access to groups you manage, which does not apply in that case.

`/group-id/members` would be the endpoint, you can definitely get the members if the group is public.

Comment: Thank you. The group is CLOSED. I am a member of it. Is there any way to retrieve all members via the API?

Comment: no, afaik it is not possible if you don´t manage the group. most likely for privacy reasons, else every user could publish a list of all members. you may not want that in a closed group.